# A problem on inner product space of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I have to find a polynomial $q \in P_2(\Bbb R)$ (vector space of all polynomials of degree less than or equal to 2) such that $$p\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\int_{0}^{1}p(x)q(x)dx$$ for every $p \in P_2(\Bbb R)$. Now, if this inner product is same for all $p \in P_2(\Bbb R)$ then it has to be zero. Am I wrong ?

Comment: But it is not the same for all $p \in P_2(\mathbb{R})$. The left hand side also depends on $p$. So no, $q$ doesn't have to be zero.

Answer (score 3):

Just check the condition for the basis vectors $\{1, t, t^2\}\subset P_2(\mathbb{R})$. If
$$
q(t) = xt^2 + yt + z
$$
then you will get
$$
\int_0^1 t^2q(t) = \frac{1}{4}
$$
which amounts to
$$
\frac{x}{5} + \frac{y}{4} + \frac{z}{3} = \frac{1}{4}
$$
Similarly,
$$
\frac{x}{4} + \frac{y}{3} + \frac{z}{2} = \frac{1}{2}
$$
and
$$
\frac{x}{3} + \frac{y}{2} + z = 1
$$
Can you solve these simultaneously?